# a ng-if with 3 condition doesn't work? angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I tried to have 3 conditions in the same ng-if and my app stopped scrolling.... 
I separated the 3 conditions in 2 divs, 2 conditions first div, and 1 condition in the second div and now it works... but I dont understand why...

params.schedule value is undefined-undefined-

```
<div class="inputs-row" ng-if="params.schedule.length > 0 && params.schedule != undefined">
                        <div ng-if="params.schedule != 'undefined-undefined-'">
                            <div class="inputCol">
                                {{'ScheduleDate' | translate}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="inputCol">
                                {{params.schedule}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Can anyone validate this or explan it?

Comment: Why would `params.schedule = 'undefined-undefined-'` (a string) to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of your logic so that the thing that is most likely to fail comes first. You can also use implied "truthiness" to simplify this logic

```
ng-if="params.schedule && params.schedule.length && params.schedule != 'undefined-undefined-'"
```

If `params.schedule` is false (undefined), it stops there. All good.

If you check `params.schedule.length` FIRST and `params.schedule` is undefined, it will error out because you're checking for a property of something that is undefined.

If `if(params.schedule.length > 0)` is the same this as `if(params.schedule.length)` because any non-zero length = true.

Here's a good primer on using truthiness: https://codeburst.io/javascript-null-vs-undefined-20f955215a2

Answer (score 1):

Your condition looks wrong.

`params.schedule.length > 0 && params.schedule != undefined`

Let's go through it.

If `params.schedule.length` is greater than 0, so it cannot be `undefined` for sure. 
Using an `&&`, in this order the conditions don't make sense and it is error prone if `params.schedule` is undefined, because you will get an error evaulating the length property as first condition (cannot access length property of undefined).

I think you are checking if `params.schedule` is an array.

There is a really cleaner and simpler way to do it in js: `Array.isArray` method.

Change your ng-if with:

```
ng-if="Array.isArray(params.schedule) && params.schedule.length" // that already checks if it's greater than 0 because if (0) === false
```